# Required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python, I've already searched over Stackoverflow and basic examples but they didn't answer my simple question:

I have this Class

```
processInstances = [subprocess.Popen] * 5
class ProcessManager:
    def startMultipleProcess(self):
        global processInstances
        for i in range(5):
            processInstances[i] = subprocess.Popen([myprocess],
                                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    def stopMultipleProcess(self):
        global processInstances
        for instance in processInstances:
            instance.terminate()
```

When the function stopMultipleProcess is called the script will crash with the error

> TypeError: terminate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

I don't understand what's wrong here, I'm coming from Java and this looks good to me.

Comment: When creating functions of a class, you must at least pass `self` to the function. So, `def startMultipleProcess(self):` and `def stopMultipleProcess(self):`

Comment: You can use `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` to define methods that don't need an instance.

Comment: Why are you initializing `processInstances` to a list of functions?

Comment: You don't need `global processInstances`. You never assign the variable, you just reference it.

Comment: `processInstances = [subprocess.Popen] * 5` - this does not do what you think it does, and it doesn't really do anything useful. I suspect your problem is also caused by calling `stopMultipleProcesses` before calling `startMultipleProcesses`, but I can't be sure because this isn't a [mcve].

Comment: @Barmar really, `processInstances = [subprocess.Popen] * 5` is a list with 5 reference to the same class!

Comment: @kaya3 How am I supposed to initialise that var then?  processInstances = None?

Comment: If I don't initialise the var I'll not be able to use it in different functions

Comment: @GMX Just create an empty list and use `append()` to add to it

Answer (score 0):

In python the self parameter in class methods acts in the same way as 'this' in java. It is used to access instance variables and methods as well as class methods and variables. If you don't need to access any instance variables you can make the method static or a class method. Static methods in python can be called without instantiating the class. Class methods can also be called without instantiating the class but will have access to class variables and methods.

here is an example class showing the different method types

```
class MyClass:
    C = "cat"

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @staticmethod
    def add(x: int, y: int):
        return x + y

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls, x: str):
        return cls.C + x

    def instance_method(self):
        return self.C + str(self.a + self.b)


a = MyClass.add(3, 5)
b = MyClass.class_method(" and dogs")
my_class = MyClass(1, 2)
c = my_class.instance_method()
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

The output is:

```
8
cat and dogs
cat3
```

As far as initializing the variable processInstances you could initialize it to an empty list then use append to add each process to the list within your loop or you could create a list initialized with None.

```
# Empty list then append
processInstances = []
processInstances.append(subprocess.Popen([myprocess],
                                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT))
# initializing a list with None
processInstances = [None for x in range(5)]
```